# Codecov with Circle CI coverage source

Tags: circleci, codecov

In my project am using **circleCI** with **codecov** for a Springboot maven project.

Below is relevant part of the .circleci/config.yml

```
 # run tests! and gen code coverage
  - run: mvn integration-test cobertura:cobertura

  - store_test_results:
      path: target/surfire-reports

  - run:
      name: Send to CodeCov
      command: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)enter code here
```

And the maven plug-in is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <formats>
        <format>html</format>
        <format>xml</format>
      </formats>
      <check/>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And am using the default codecov.yml which can be found [here](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/codecov-yaml#section-default-yaml).

The circleci build is successful and I do get a codecov report generated BUT the code coverage is only for files within the **bootsrap** package of the project `com.x.y.bootstrap`.

Below is an image from codecov site for the repository.
[image]

What am looking for is full code coverage of the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem was due to the `cobertura-maven-plugin` not picking-up the correct source class path; hence generating the report with invalid data. I've updated the project to use `jacoco-maven-plugin` and simply ran the tests with:

> - run: mvn integration-test

The POM file change was as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Everything worth after that.